# how to limit java process RAM usage

Tags: java, jvm

in the heap ,we can use -Xms -Xmx to limit ram the useage.

outside of jvm's heap,when use the NIO.we can use -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize.

but in the progame like this

```
public class MappedBufferTest {
    static long length = 1024*1024*512; //
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try (FileChannel fc = new RandomAccessFile("data.txt", "rw").getChannel()) {
            MappedByteBuffer out = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, length);
            int i = 0;
            for (; i < length/2; i++) {
                out.put((byte) 'x');
            }
            Thread.sleep(30*1000);
            System.out.println("writing");
            for (; i < length; i++) {
                out.put((byte) 'x');
            }
            System.out.println("Finished writing");
            Thread.sleep(60*1000);
            fc.close();
        }
    }
```

}

with jvm options

-Xms256m -Xmx256m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=128m

it runs well.it does not occur oom error.

-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize is not working?

java 1.8  os:centos

Comment: what do you mean by not working? What is the error?

Comment: `MaxDirectMemorySize` limits memory allocated by `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect`. Mapped byte buffers are not counted. Since they are backed by a file, they do not necessary occupy RAM - OS may flush pages to disk at any time it thinks necessary.

Comment: in the os's monitor. i can the process 's ram grow up to 512m. why   does  if not limit 128m .

Comment: This option is not meant to limit RAM usage

Answer (score 0):

You can use ulimit to limit the amount of virtual memory available to the process, which includes mapped files. But then you'll have to account for all the JVM's needs to avoid it being killed.

If you're only concerned about resident memory you can also use cgroups.

Comment: thanks for your help. cgroups may help me solve the problem. I still confuse the -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize useage.

Comment: @jin This limits ByteBuffers created with `Bytes.allocateDirect(n)`

Answer (score 0):

Mapped files don't use private memory. You are utilising the OS'es disk cache.

While memory mapped files increase the virtual memory, the data is paged as needed so even if you mapped files larger than you main memory, you still won't exceed the limits you set.

NOTE: A file can be in memory because you accessed it recently. If a program happen to memory map it, it doesn't mean the program is using that much memory as it would have been used whether the program was running or not.

e.g. on Linux you can map in a 100 TB file without increasing heap or direct memory usage.